# Difference b/w Mapr Vs Cloudera?

Tags: cloudera, mapr

Cloudera is free edition and enterprise edition but MapR is almost enterprise edition why? is there any major difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Cloudera and MapR are Big data platforms. In Cloudera have three editions, one is free, enterprise edition up to 60 days and full enterprise edition. In free edition, some services are not there compare with enterprise edition. There is no default security.
http://commandstech.com/mapr-vs-cloudera-vs-hortonworks/
In MapR has completely enterprise edition because of it has own security and inbuilt services are there and finance domains are used mostly. High availability also more compare with Cloudera

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera is basically just Apache Hadoop including Spark and Hive with some management tools. It is largely limited to HDFS operation.

MapR is a much more versatile system. It supports Apache software like Hadoop, Spark, Hive and Drill, but it goes far beyond that as well. Support for Kubernetes is excellent (including very conventional software like postgres or mySQL) and you can mix and match conventional software with big data software freely. You can also mix in machine learning and AI software without having to copy data around to specialist clusters.

In addition, you can run various HPC (high performance computing) systems directly on MapR without having to convert them to use big data APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera runs on HDFS wheras MAPR runs on MAPRFS. HDFS is append only whereas MAPRFS allows random read/writes making it highly efficient. This effectively means MAPR can provide the same performance in much lesser memory requirement than HDFS. The lowest unit or read/write is much smaller in MAPRFS. HDFS is a distributed file system but underneath it uses linux file system to write data to the actual disk. This is lack of control on optimization during actual writes on raw disk, in MapR they directly have the native code which writes directly into disks in an optimized way. This itself is single big reason for improved writes.Since the code is written in C, there is no need of JVM garbage collection.
For further details, you could look up the link :
https://mapr.com/blog/database-comparison-an-in-depth-look-at-mapr-db/